# can someone help how can i get random math operator ( kotlin)

Tags: java, kotlin

hello guys am new to kotlin
i try to make a quiz app , so the questions that included strings i put them manually
and math questions are random ( loop )
the help i ask for how can i get random math operator here

```
 println("${randomNumber1} * ${randomNumber2}")
```

also `println("${randomNumber1} * ${randomNumber2}")`

part from the code :

```
   try {
            for (i in defaultMain until defaultMain+40) {
                val randomNumber1 = (0..30).random()
                val randomNumber2 = (1..10).random()
                println("${randomNumber1} * ${randomNumber2}")
                var input = readLine()!!.toInt()
                when (input) {
                    randomNumber1 * randomNumber2 -> "Right! 5 Points added to your score , and 5+ bonus"
                    else -> lose() }
                this.bonus =  this.bonus + 5
                this.score = this.score + 5
                this.score = this.score +  this.bonus
                println("Your current score: ${this.score}")
            }
        } catch (e : Exception)
        {
            println(e.message)
            exitProcess(0)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

define operators in an array like below and access from index by generating random number:

```
char[] x = { '-', '+', '*', '/', '^', '%' };
Random random = new Random();
int random_operator = random.nextInt(x.length);
System.out.println(x[random_operator]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
val randomNumber1 = (0..30).random()
val randomNumber2 = (1..10).random()
val operator = (1..4).random()

val solution = when (operator) {
    1 -> {
        println("$randomNumber1 * $randomNumber2")
        randomNumber1 * randomNumber2
    }
    2 -> {
        println("$randomNumber1 / $randomNumber2")
        randomNumber1 / randomNumber2
    }
    3 -> {
        println("$randomNumber1 - $randomNumber2")
        randomNumber1 - randomNumber2
    }
    else -> {
        println("$randomNumber1 + $randomNumber2")
        randomNumber1 + randomNumber2
    }
}
var input = readLine()!!.toInt()
if (input == solution)
    println("Right! 5 Points added to your score , and 5+ bonus")
else
    lose()
```